# How to populate same layout xml several times?

Tags: java, android

[image: Japan -> ListView of]

After this when the user click soba i want to show an image And description on how to make it the recipe in different layout.But after that if they click soup 
i want use the same layout file to different image and description.

Can i use same layout xml file to do so OR make different layout xlm for all, if so how do i do it.

And how to set Onclicklistener on ListView.

I'm using custom `ArrayAdapter<food>`.

I am new to android and this is my first app so any help would be great .

Thank you in advance .

Comment: Look for `RecyclerView` tutorials .

Comment: You can use recyclerview for this.  For more details: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 2 activities, ListActivity which looks like in your posted picture, and DetailActivity that shows the recipe detail and how to cook it. Then you can do it like this:

1. Add OnItemClickListener to your listview.
2. Make sure you chose the information to you want to send to the DetailActivity so it will know which recipe is clicked (eg: the recipe ID).
3. Inside the OnItemClicked method, create an Intent object, then put the information to that intent via Intent.putExtra() method.
4. Inside the OnCreate method in DetailActivity, retrieve the intent extra data, and validate it do determine what to show based on the clicked recipe.

Comment: you didn't get his question.

Comment: sorry But it did not work But i found another way to do it . Thx for the info .